# jquery fadeout/fadein flicker issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

i have read several posts on this but none seems to solve my issue,
when I fadeout a gallery, the other fades in, that works fine...but the item that fades in seems to 'refresh' or fade in again (real quick) after the fadein animation completed, here's my code:

what I have is basically a photo gallery (photographySection) contained inside a 'mediaContainer', this is the css:

```
.mediaContainer {
   position: relative;
}
.photographySection {
    top: 10px;
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

html:

```
 <div class='mediaContainer'>              
       <div class='photographySection hidden' id='photographyExperimental'>
            <ul><li><img src...></li></ul>
        </div>
        <div class='photographySection hidden' id='photographyFaces'>
             <ul><li><img src...></li></ul>
        </div>
 </div>
```

js:

```
$(".photographyMenu").click(function(event){
    $(".photographySection").hide(1,function() { // hide all sections
        var section = $(event.target).attr("section"); // read new section to show
        $("#"+section).fadeIn(500); // for example $("#photographyFaces")
    }); 
});
```

everything works smoothly, but sometimes after the chosen div fades in, it flickers/blinks once for some reason

thanks!

Comment: Can you set up a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need all that markup for such a simple task? If all you want is just fade a bunch of images in and out, you could do something like this:

html markup:

```
<div class="mediaContainer">
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function fadeInOut(){
    var imgs = $('.mediaContainer > img');
    imgs.wrapAll('<div class="slideshow" />');

    $('.slideshow > img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.slideshow > img:first')
            .fadeOut(500)
            .next('img')
            .fadeIn(500)
            .end()
            .appendTo('.slideshow');
    }, 5000);
}
```

Maybe someone more experienced can improve upon this code. You can also set vars to those "magic numbers" (500/5000) and some other things, but that should solve the problem with much less code (just an option).

Comment: i have about 5 galleries, and each gallery is loading a list of images from a database, so there's alot of images, grouped by categories...I'm creating a menu to switch between different categories

Comment: ah, ok... Well, I still think you have way too much markup but you can improve on that later. The problem happens in every browser? I've being facing some fading problems with Webkit browsers (Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use the 500, and it will work smoother, slow is 600miliseconds and normal is 400miliseconds

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one: **http://jsfiddle.net/S4sbm/**

```
$(".photographySection:gt(0)").hide();
    $(".photographyMenu").click(function(event){   
    $(".photographySection").fadeOut(500);    
    var section = $(event.target).attr("section"); // read new section to show         
    $("#"+section+':hidden').fadeIn(500); // for example $("#photographyFaces")        
});
```

checkout the fiddle and see if this helps.